# Google drive - alter a shared spreadsheet without oauth

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to edit a shared spreadsheet on Google Drive programatically.
I'm using C#

When the user clicks a button, my code should use the company dev account + password to access a spreadsheet on google drive and update a date field. That's all it needs to do.

It looks to me like oAuth requires the user themselves to authenticate with google, or at least that's the impression I get from Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2AuthorizeAsync()

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Asynchronously authorizes the specified user. Requires user interaction; see
    //     Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker remarks for more details.
    //
```

This is not what I need or want, but the documentation around this seems totally opaque... Maybe I'm missing something here?
Does anyone know of another way to do this?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587763/how-to-provide-credentials-programmatically-to-use-google-drive-api-in-c-sharp-o

Comment: I have edited your question and fixed the tag as editing a file is done using the sheets api not the drive api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update anything you need to be authenticated even if the sheet is set to public and anyone can access it.   Programmaticly speaking you still need to be authenticated.

What you should look into using is a service account.   Service accounts are like dummy users if you share the sheet with the service account using the service account email address.  It will then have access to the sheet without needing to be authenticated.

```
public static class ServiceAccountExample
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Authenticating to Google using a Service account
    /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceAccountEmail">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
    /// <param name="serviceAccountCredentialFilePath">Location of the .p12 or Json Service account key file downloaded from Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
    /// <returns>AnalyticsService used to make requests against the Analytics API</returns>
    public static SheetsService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, string[] scopes)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("Path to the service account credentials file is required.");
            if (!File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("The service account credentials file does not exist at: " + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail))
                throw new Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.");                

            // For Json file
            if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".json")
            {
                GoogleCredential credential;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                         .CreateScoped(scopes);
                }

                // Create the  Analytics service.
                return new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Sheets Service account Authentication Sample",
                });
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".p12")
            {   // If its a P12 file

                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = scopes
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                // Create the  Sheets service.
                return new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Sheets Authentication Sample",
                });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unsupported Service accounts credentials.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountSheetsFailed", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

code ripped from my sample project [ServiceAccount.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Sheets%20API/v4/ServiceAccount.cs)

Comment: Beautiful. Just what I wanted.